# wordpress - Error establishing a database connection lost password

Tags: wordpress

I made the mistake of moving a wordpress site from a dev folder on my hosting account, to a new hosting account of its own late last night.

I copied all the wordpress related files, and put them on the new server, i set up a username and password, although there was a prefilled in prefix for the database/user - so i adjusted this in the wp-config.php file. I thought i was nearly there...  aparantly not.

When i try to visit the site, i get a Error establishing a database connection message.

and likewise when i try to access the wp-admin dashboard.

Is there a way to reset everything to do with the user details without wiping my whole website?  I think i must have uploaded the incorrect details to my existing server also, as i'm now getting the same error message there.

It was all working fine before i attempted to migrate the site. :(

Comment: on your new hosting enviroment have you created a new MySQL user? and password? And I have you added this user to the database and given it the correct permissions?

Comment: Check host, username, password and db name all must be corrected.

Comment: Ah, great... I was pretty sure i'd covered all that - several times... the site loads now. however when i visit the /wp-admin page, it gets redirected to the wp-admin page on the other hosting account. How do i change that?

Comment: It's okay, I found the references in the wordpress database to my old site... thanks for your help guys

Comment: @sturobinson81 so was it the missing SQL user permissions?